# Sanity error on deployment using Vercel Type error: Module '"sanity"' has no exported member 'defineConfig'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, sanity

Im am trying to deploy my app and Vercel screams that a module of sanity has no exported member. I ran my build as well in my terminal, same issue. I degraded & updated my sanity/client packages and it did not help.[image]

Here is a look at my terminal + file [image]

Answer (score 0):

Move your sanity client config file (aka wherever you have your .env variables setup - in my case: sanity.ts) into a lib folder in the root directory. If the file itself is in the root directory, it will not build.